# Dart: Store heavy object in an isolate and access its method from main isolate without reinstatiating it

Tags: multithreading, flutter, dart, multiprocessing, dart-isolates

is it possible in Dart to instantiate a class in an isolate, and then send message to this isolate to receive a return value from its methods (instead of  spawning a new isolate and re instantiate the same class every time)? I have a class with a long initialization, and heavy methods. I want to initialize it once and then access its methods without compromising the performance of the main isolate.

Comment: could you please provide some code snippets?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** I mistakenly answered this question thinking python rather than dart. <sub>snakes on the brain / snakes on a plane</sub>

I am not familiar with dart programming, but it would seem the concurrency model has a lot of similarities (isolated memory, message passing, etc..). I was able to find [an example](https://medium.com/@lelandzach/dart-isolate-2-way-communication-89e75d973f34) of 2 way message passing with a dart `isolate`. There's a little difference in how it gets set-up, and the streams are a bit simpler than python `Queue`'s, but in general the idea is the same.

Basically:

- Create a port to receive data from the isolate
- Create the isolate passing it the port it will send data back on
- Within the isolate, create the port it will listen on, and send the other end of it back to main (so main can send messages)
- Determine and implement a simple messaging protocol for remote method call on an object contained within the isolate.

---

This is basically duplicating what a `multiprocessing.Manager` class does, however it can be helpful to have a simplified example of how it can work:

```py
from multiprocessing import Process, Lock, Queue
from time import sleep

class HeavyObject:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self._x = x
        sleep(5) #heavy init

    def heavy_method(self, y):
        sleep(.2) #medium weight method
        return self._x + y

def HO_server(in_q, out_q):
    ho = HeavyObject(5)
    #msg format for remote method call: ("method_name", (arg1, arg2, ...), {"kwarg1": 1, "kwarg2": 2, ...})
    #pass None to exit worker cleanly
    for msg in iter(in_q.get, None): #get a remote call message from the queue
        out_q.put(getattr(ho, msg[0])(*msg[1], **msg[2])) #call the method with the args, and put the result back on the queue

class RMC_helper: #remote method caller for convienience
    def __init__(self, in_queue, out_queue, lock):
        self.in_q = in_queue
        self.out_q = out_queue
        self.l = lock
        self.method = None

    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.method is None:
            raise Exception("no method to call")
        with self.l: #isolate access to queue so results don't pile up and get popped off in possibly wrong order
            print("put to queue: ", (self.method, args, kwargs))
            self.in_q.put((self.method, args, kwargs))
            return self.out_q.get()

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if not name.startswith("__"):
            self.method = name
            return self
        else:
            super().__getattr__(name)

def child_worker(remote):
    print("child", remote.heavy_method(5)) #prints 10
    sleep(3) #child works on something else
    print("child", remote.heavy_method(2)) #prints 7


if __name__ == "__main__":
    in_queue = Queue()
    out_queue = Queue()
    lock = Lock() #lock is used as to not confuse which reply goes to which request

    remote = RMC_helper(in_queue, out_queue, lock)

    Server = Process(target=HO_server, args=(in_queue, out_queue))
    Server.start()

    Worker = Process(target=child_worker, args=(remote, ))
    Worker.start()

    print("main", remote.heavy_method(3)) #this will *probably* start first due to startup time of child

    Worker.join()

    with lock:
        in_queue.put(None)
        Server.join()
    print("done")
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, however, the language is dart not python. Dart achieves multiprocessing using isolates which differ from traditional threads (do not share memory). My question is how to use isolates in the given case.

Comment: @J.Gatica my bad... too many tabs open

Comment: I think the comparison may still be useful however as python processes also don't share memory, and must pass messages via pipes (`Queue` is just some extra sauce around a standard pipe).